# Angulars : adding params to directive function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change the params of the function call passed to directive.

**HTML**

```
<div direx onabc="a.b({'a':10,'b':13});" >
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('direx', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            onabc:'&onabc'
        },
            controller: function($scope,a){
     $scope.a=a; //a service  
    //In controller of this directive which is called by ng-click

 $scope.ngClicked = function() {
    // WANT TO CHANGE A PARAM TO CALL OF abc()
    $scope.value=100;   
    $scope.onabc({"b":$scope.value}); // should call a.b({a:10,b:100});
    return result;
 };
         }
```

Comment: what is `a.b`? is it a real function `b` on object `a`?

Comment: yes .. b is a function in a service a, .directive('direx', function($compile,a) ..

Comment: it's not clear in your code. post the surrounding code as well. like the parent controller or directives.

Comment: updated controller which takes a sevice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are injecting the service in your controller / scope, you don't need to pass the function to your isolated scope.

**HTML**

```html
<div direx onabc="{'a':10,'b':13}"></div>
```

**Directive**

```js
.directive('direx', ['a', function(a){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'onabc': '@'
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="ngClicked()">Click me {{ value }}</div>',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.ngClicked = function() {                
          // WANT TO CHANGE A PARAM TO CALL OF abc()
          value = $scope.$eval($scope.onabc);
          $scope.value = value.b = 100;
          a.b(value); // should call a.b({a:10,b:100});
      };      
    }]
  };
}])
```

See the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/z7lpfoKCS2bR3bRzsuwB?p=preview

Comment: No. it doesn't work out because i want to separate out the functionality and don't want to put a.b() into the directive

Comment: don't inject your service in your directive then

Comment: don't quite agree .. if i have a.b(), a.c(), a.d() .. i can call any in my case .. but not in yours

Comment: what stops you from using `a[value.fn](value.params);`? your declaration would turn to `<div direx onabc="{'fn':'b','params':{'a': 13}}"></div>` (which is overkill IMHO) or even `<div direx onabc="b" onabc-params="{'b':13}"></div>`

Comment: hmm this is good but also bad since i can't add more services or functions in other scopes.

Comment: a directive should do one thing and do well. you are trying to create a "catch-all" solution for spaghetti code...

Answer (score 0):

"b" in your object has to be a separate parameter if you want to provide a "local" value in your directive. This is how locals work when invoking a function through angular. In other words, when you are saying:

```
$scope.onabc({"b":$scope.value});
```

you are telling angular to use this local definition of b rather than the one that would exist on the other scope... In fact, you have to do some renaming to get this to work as "b" would replace your a.b which is not what you want... Let's call your local object mydata. Then put mydata onto your directive in your HTML (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/638u6/)):

```
<div direx onabc="a.b({'a':10,'b':13}, mydata);" >
```

JavaScript:

```
mod.service("a", function () {
    //take in mydata as another parameter for locals data
    this.b = function (original, mydata) {
        alert("original a: " + original.a);
        alert("original b: " + original.b);
        alert("locals mydata: " + mydata.b);
    }
});

mod.directive('direx', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            onabc:'&onabc'
        },
        template: '<div><button type="button" ng-click="ngClicked()">Click Me</button></div>',
        controller: function($scope,a) {
             $scope.a=a; //a service  

             $scope.ngClicked = function() {
                $scope.value=100;   
                 //define values for mydata, replace b with $scope.value here.
                 $scope.onabc({mydata: {b: $scope.value}});
             };
        }
    }
});
```

Now if you wanted to add more data to the locals you could do so:

```
$scope.onabc({mydata: {a: 50, b: 100}});
```

Now mydata.a and mydata.b would be what you push in through your directive.